# Linux (Redhat 7.5) Patching

Tags: redhat-satellite

I was trying to update a redhat 7.5 server, but it was giving the below error-

```
Loaded plugins: langpacks, rhnplugin
There was an error communicating with RHN.
Red Hat Satellite or RHN Classic support will be disabled.
Error communicating with server. The message was:

Error Message:
    Please run rhn_register as root on this client
Error Class Code: 9
Error Class Info: Invalid System Credentials.
Explanation:
     An error has occurred while processing your request. If this problem
     persists please consult the Red Hat Customer Portal Knowledge Base
     landing page on common registration Error Class Codes at
     https://access.redhat.com/solutions/17036 for a possible resolution.
     If you choose to open a support case in the Red Hat Customer Portal,
     please be sure to include details of what you were trying to do when
     this error occurred and specifics on how to reproduce this problem.

No packages marked for update
```

I tried to register the server with satellite but got the below error-

```
REGISTRATION
------------
* registering
Error communicating with server. The message was:
Connection timed out on readline

*** Error: Registering the system failed.
```

Comment: You need to provide more information. Your current errors just tell me that your server doesn’t have an active subscription and can’t communicate with your Satellite server. Do you have other RHEL 7 servers that are registered and talk with Satellite?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a connection error. You should check your ipconfig and your resolv.conf file to make sure your nameserver is set correctly.